# GridView - input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a gridview control that uses templatefield CYQ2. I have formatted the field as currency in html using `Text = '<%# Bind("CYQ2","{0:$#,##0.00}") %>'` and it displays the field in the currency format. When I update values in the app and hit the save button, I get an error that says "**input string was not in a correct format**" at the line that is bold and italicized below.

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        originalDataTable = (System.Data.DataTable)ViewState["originalValuesDataTable"];

        foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
            ***if (IsRowModified(r)) { GridView1.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, false); }***
```

In the IsRowModified event(code behind file), am using

```
currentQ2 = Decimal.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("CYQ2TextBox")).Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

I tried several other techniques such as NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol and CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in the code behind file but nothing worked.

The point to note here is that if I use the following in the HTML markup(without dollar symbol), it works without nay issue but I need to display the dollar symbol.
`Text = '<%# Bind("CYQ2","{0:#,##0.00}") %>'`

Can anyone please help? thanks for the help.

Additional Information(complete HTML markup of the templatefield):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Q2" SortExpression="CYQ2">
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="CYTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CYQ2") %>' Width="40"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="CYQ2TextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="40"
                Text = '<%# Bind("CYQ2","{0:$#,##0}") %>' Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>        
               <HeaderStyle Width="40px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt"/>
              <ItemStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />    
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Is the exception occurring at the call to `Decimal.Parse` in `IsRowModified`, or at the call to `GridView1.UpdateRow`?

Comment: Have you considered using an ASP.NET Label control instead of TextBox for the `ItemTemplate` and then putting another label in front of that, which just displays a hardcoded dollar sign (`$`)? This would allow you to display the dollar sign without the hassle of accounting for it in your logic. I could post the code for this as an answer if you would like, but I don't want to offer an answer for a solution that is not appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Try changing `Text = '<%# Bind("CYQ2","{0:$#,##0}") %>'` to `Text = '<%# Bind("CYQ2","{0:C}") %>'` to get the currency format easily.

Comment: Michael - The exception is occurring at GridView1.UpdateRow. I already tried 'Text = '<%# Bind("CYQ2","{0:C}")%>'' and got the same error. Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: Can you share the specific value of CYQ2TextBox.Text (or one specific example) when this error is thrown? does the value conform to the expectations outlined in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx)?  (PS - you need to put an "@" symbol before someone's name to notify them of your comments).  @MichaelLiu Probably doesn't know you responded to him yet.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - Thanks for your reply. The way I have setup the gridview, it will pre-populate it with 0s and so the number looks like $0 and if I change it to anything like $10, it will give me the error, even if I just try to save without changing anything.

Comment: I think you may need to handle the GridView's RowUpdating event, look at the NewValues property of the EventArgs, and correct the format of the value.

Comment: @MichaelLiu - Thanks for your reply again. Can you please provide more details? How can I correct the format of the value and where is the NewValues property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the data source control you're using has simplistic parsing logic that chokes on dollar signs. Fortunately, the [`GridView.RowUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) event gives you a chance to manipulate row values before they're sent on to the data source control.

In your .aspx, add an `OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"` attribute to your `GridView`, and handle the event like so:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string value = e.NewValues["CYQ2"].ToString();
    // "value" is the text entered by the user, including the dollar sign.
    // Parse the value with the Currency style so that the data source can handle it:
    e.NewValues["CYQ2"] = decimal.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Currency);
}
```